# merge same rows and show different fields in new column in sql

Tags: sql, merge

i have a table:

[image]

and i want this result:

[image]

Comment: Any idea to solve the issue. Also tag the `RDBMS` that you are using

Comment: Please don't post images of your problem, show us the text.

Comment: Most people here prefer formatted text instead of images.

Comment: And don't forget to add what SQL you've done so far to solve the problem.

Comment: How to pick SnPrs and sTime values?

Comment: What if more than two rows are there for `Sn,SnPrs,SdayDate` combination

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are maximum of two rows, this will work

```
select Srn, SrnPrs,sDayDate,max(sTime) as sTime1, min(sTime) as sTime2 from table
group by  Srn, SrnPrs,sDayDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Sn,sDayDate, GROUP_CONCAT(string SEPARATOR ' ') FROM table GROUP BY Sn;
```

Comment: How do you know he's using MySQL?